# How To Connect To phpadmin 000WebHost?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I create a sql db then move to phpAdmin page of 000WebHost, but it can't connect when i type password, i don't know what happen, please someone help me, my password is right and I try for many time

[Here is my Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSFrn.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the password you entered is correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, i don't know what happen but i try type each character slowly

Comment: I suggest asking your host for assistance with the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phpMyAdmin version is *severely* outdated. Not only are you missing a lot of features and vulnerable to security flaws, but that version is not even able to interact with modern MySQL or PHP versions. Presumably, the reason you're having trouble is because of these version incompatibilities (for instance, MySQL changed their authentication method and PHP has changed the library used to access MySQL).

You should upgrade to a more recent version of phpMyAdmin that's compatible with your MySQL and PHP versions. You should pursue it through your host, since that's what you're paying them for and all, but if you wish you certainly [can install your own](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install). Basically, download the file and uncompress it to your web root, then optionally create a `config.inc.php` to customize any settings you wish.

Comment: So how can i update, this version is of 000webhost, i'm using Xampp and my phpMyAdmin is version 4.5.1, newer than. Tell me what should i do ?

Comment: Well, since it's provided by your host, you should ask their support folks for assistance with the connection problem and ask them about updating their provided phpMyAdmin version. However, I've also edited my answer for instructions on installing your own.